# VB 6.0 Out of Memory Error

Tags: vb6

One of my VB 6.0 application throws an error "Out of memory" when loading the form in a particular system, but works fine in other machines. But other vb 6.0 application works fine in the same Machine.

Problematic Machine Details:
Windows XP, HP load runner installed

Other Machines:
Windows 2003

I tried so many ways to find the root cause but i couldn't. Please help me out to find the root cause..

Thanks,
Gunasekaran Sambandhan

Comment: please put some more details in. What is the form doing? Can you run it under debug. What's in the windows logs etc. What have you tried to narrow down the differences?

Comment: Windows Log: Out of memory, raises when form.show. simple form with 4 Tabs and each tab contains list view and 2 command buttons.

Comment: Does the problem machine have an equivalent hardware spec to the others, e.g the amount of RAM. May also be worth checking the amount of virtual memory the system has set aside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i found the solution for this issue. One specific dll (MSSTDFMT.DLL) of this project is missing in this particular machine. I have placed and registered the dll. Now it is working fine.

Thanks,
Gunasekaran Sambandhan

Comment: Well done mate! Could I ask you to perhaps put how you tracked the issue in the answer for other people who may see this this error and come to your question in the future?

Comment: thanks mate.. 1. i googled to find the solution, unfortunately i didn't get exact solution. but i got some clue in bits & pieces. like dll duplication in the system, FM20.dll might be the cause, COM control issue.. etc.., 2. using that i tried to fix the issue, but no result. 3. As a hole i come to know that some specific dll is got corrupted which is used by this VB project. 4. fortunately i have very less dll in my project, so i tried to find the missing dll in the system. 5. I found MSSTDFMT.DLL got missed, so i have placed the dll in the system and registered the dll in that system

Answer (score 1):

Want to add our fix since it took us days to figure out what was going on.

We were trying to get an old VB6 program to run on Windows 7, we'd gotten it to work on other PCs but this one was giving us problems. Apparently we were missing a dependency, and often this misleading error can be due to missing dependencies.

The particular dependency we were missing was FM20.DLL which we got by installing Microsoft ActiveX Control Pad (http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-ActiveX-Control-Pad/3000-2070_4-127950.html)

Answer (score 1):

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe MSSTDFMT.DLL

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if the registration of one or more modules gets messed up, the message "[7] Out of Memory" may occur.   Unregistering and then registering the DLL(s) will fix the problem in that case.  (Just encountered this on a machine that was "scrubbed" by a network push - IT could not tell me what they scrubbed exactly.)